# SilverStripe how to return JSON headers

Tags: json, http-headers, silverstripe

My controller method `Foo()` (which is called through AJAX request) prints a JSON to the page using `json_encode($data)`. I'm trying to accompany the correct http headers by using

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

But from my browser development tools I read the AJAX response:

```
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
```

I'm assuming the JSON headers aren't sent correctly. Is this the right way to send JSON headers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a Controller context, you would add this header like so:

```
$this->getResponse()->addHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
```

If you are doing it from outside of a Controller then you need to create a new `SS_HTTPResponse` object and return it with the added header, as above. [Here's an example](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-graphql/blob/2eda02ae1b5af8eb66f566b3f2320f8b6325b57e/src/Controller.php#L74-L75) of `silverstripe/graphql` doing this (in a SilverStripe 4 module).

Answer (score 1):

Faloude in the past I've done `return SS_HTTPRequest::send_file($file, $fileName, 'Content-Type: text/csv');` for returning csv files with the header. I'm guessing you could update the 3rd parameter to be `application/json` and it should work fine.